# Insert a new database in redis using redis.StrictRedis()

Tags: python, database, redis, redis-py

I know that Redis have 16 databases by default, but what if i need to add another database, how can i do that using redis-py?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. The number of databases is not a dynamic parameter in Redis.

You can change it by updating the Redis configuration file (databases parameter) and restarting the server.

From a client (Python or other), you can retrieve this value using the "GET CONFIG DATABASES" command. But the "SET CONFIG DATABASES xxx" command will be rejected.